# The local source file for AngularJS is not found

Tags: angularjs

I am practicing basic AngularJS examples. The main issue I have been facing is that the `angular.min.js` file that I saved on my desktop is not found. I tried using the file location from one example at Plunker, which works perfectly fine.

This is the location that I use in my code:

```
<script src="C:\Users\Abdul Hadi\Desktop\angular\lib\angular\angular.min.js"></script>
```

And the output is like this:

```
{{author.name}}

{{author.title + ',' + author.company}}
```

But when I use this, it works perfectly fine:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) (`file:///`) to load local files.

```
<script src="file:///C:\Users\Abdul Hadi\Desktop\angular\lib\angular\angular.min.js"></script>
```

I would use slashes instead of backslashes and a relative path, but it works anyway.